# Use Google Colab Resources on local IDE

Tags: ide, data-science, google-colaboratory

I have a big doubt... is see a lot of [blog posts](https://robotwealth.com/how-to-connect-google-colab-to-a-local-jupyter-runtime/) where they say that you can use the Colab front-end to edit a local Jupiter Notebook

However I don't see the point... the actual advantage would be to use something like DataSpell or some local IDE, on a remote Notebook on Colab, and use the Colab Resources to do the computations, so you have:

1. IDE level of suggestions (Colab is pretty slow compared to local IDE)
2. cloud computing performances and advantages

Hoever, I don't see any blog talking about this... is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like [colab-ssh](https://github.com/WassimBenzarti/colab-ssh) but Google has cracked down on these tools making the whole process inconvenient in one way or another. I think a better approach would be to just use your IDE as you would and store your notebooks on GitHub. Git-to-Colab is officially supported and you're obviously not doing heavy computing or long-running tasks during development so I don't think there should be an issue. For computationally inexpensive tasks (dataviz?) Codespaces or Datalore should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Colab resources only to compute some intensive parts of your code, you can create a flask server inside Colab and expose the APIs with the code you want to execute.

Comment: @toyotaSupra I have noticed in my reviews that you have been making a large number of edits to posts, generally adding code fences. This is a good thing. However, in cases like this post, neither "Colab" nor "APIs" are code and should not be formatted as such.

Comment: Sorry about that.